# Heroku server error in SSR application on Nuxt.js + Vuetify

Tags: node.js, heroku, vuetify.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have moved settings storage from localStorage to cookies and wrote this code:

```
// set settings on server from user's cookies
middleware({ app, store }) {
  if (process.server) {
    const settings = app.$cookies.get('settings')
    store.commit('settings/updateSettings', settings)
    app.vuetify.framework.theme.isDark = settings.theme === 'dark'
  }
},
```

After I made sure that this thing works, I deployed my project to heroku. Build succeed but when I try to open [my project](https://todo-list-z.herokuapp.com/) I got error.

heroku logs:

```
2020-03-17T10:44:52.115443+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2020-03-17T10:44:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-03-17T10:44:58.534112+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run start`
2020-03-17T10:45:00.957944+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-03-17T10:45:00.957988+00:00 app[web.1]: > todo-list@1.0.0 start /app
2020-03-17T10:45:00.957989+00:00 app[web.1]: > nuxt start
2020-03-17T10:45:00.957989+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-03-17T10:45:02.077592+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-03-17T10:45:01.732667+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ Listening on: http://172.17.190.190:6215/
2020-03-17T10:45:47.632325+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-03-17T10:45:47.632336+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR  Cannot read property 'theme' of undefined
2020-03-17T10:45:47.632336+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-03-17T10:45:47.632337+00:00 app[web.1]: at middleware (server.js:1:347584)
2020-03-17T10:45:47.632338+00:00 app[web.1]: at $ (server.js:1:338697)
2020-03-17T10:45:47.632338+00:00 app[web.1]: at _ (server.js:1:338543)
2020-03-17T10:45:47.632339+00:00 app[web.1]: at n.default (server.js:1:406452)
```

console.log(app.vuetify.framework) inside middleware and that condition gives me regular object with properties.. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is your app.$cookies.get('settings') always return object?

Comment: @TenshiGoan Thank you very much for the hint!!! I cleared localStorage, cookies and then tried to start my application locally, got same error. I will work on it now. Thanks again!

Comment: @TenshiGoan write an answer here, I will mark it as a solution. This helped me: wrap up commit and applying theme with condition if (settings)